# TextView in ConstraintLayout (for MaterialCardView) not in vertical centre

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout, android-cardview, materialcardview

I'm trying to vertically align my TextView to the centre using constraints within my MaterialCardView but it won't move at all for some reason. Does anyone know what's causing this problem to occur? Do constraints need to be used at all to achieve this? The affected component is the `MaterialCardView` with a white border. The word 'Information' + the drawable don't seem to be exactly in the vertical centre for some reason. It looks like there is a bit more space above the text view than below it for some strange reason (indicated by the orange line).

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/myCardViewA"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/myConstraintLayoutA"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/myImageButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_chevron_down"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myTextViewTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/myImageButton"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myTextViewSubtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/myImageButton"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/myTextViewTitle"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/myButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:padding="12dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/myTextViewSubtitle"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/myCardViewB"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/myImageButton"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/myCardViewB"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
            app:contentPadding="12dp"
            app:cardElevation="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/myButton"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/myImageButton"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/myTextViewDescription"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/myConstraintLayoutB"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/myTextViewinCardView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
                    android:text=""
                    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"/>
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myTextViewDescription"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/myTextViewTitle"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/myCardViewB"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

**Kotlin**

```
class MyFragment : androidx.fragment.app.Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val v = view

        val imageGetter = Html.ImageGetter { name ->
            val resId = when (name) {
                "door" -> { R.drawable.ic_door }
                else -> { throw IllegalArgumentException("what is $name") }
            }

            ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, resId, requireActivity().theme)?.apply {
                setBounds(0, 0, intrinsicWidth, intrinsicHeight)
            }
        }

        val info = getString(R.string.information)
        val htmlTxt = "<img src=\"door\"/> $info
        val myTxt = Html.fromHtml(htmlTxt, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT, imageGetter, null)

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"`

The maximum is `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"`

When you set "0.0" that mean you want it to the left and when it is "1.0" that mean it is to the right.

Comment: Remove that from where?

Comment: From any view that you can’t move it, for example the textView with this id (myTextViewTitle)

Comment: You will notice that it moved to the middle

Comment: I don’t want it in the middle. I only want ‘myTextViewinCardView’ to be in the vertical centre. Notice in my screenshot there is an orange line I drew, which is extra padding or something I am seeing for some reason. That should not be there.

Comment: Okaaaay, just let me check it

Comment: the XML code above is not the same of the image Right?, Can you give me your XML code to see the error

Comment: Correct. I have added the Kotlin code to my question, where the text is added.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226201/discussion-between-mohammad-khair-pk-and-swarthy46).

Comment: The XML cover I posted in my question represents the attached image in my question. If you are able to recreate it without the extra padding, please let me know.